# Error 438 Ocurrs on other computers but not in mine

Tags: excel, vba

I've made an excel sheet intended to be shared but other users are having problems to use it. When i use it there are no errors. But people say that they are getting error 438.
I've asked them to send a screenshot of the debugging and this is what one of them sent

[image]

The object that's refreshing is a table that extracts information from a .txt file

My first suspect was that the user was inputing incorrect information on the .txt file and because of that the table wasn't recognizing it's format. However that user claims to be inputing the correct information. Also he is not the only one with that problem and it seems unlikely that 2 people could be inserting the wrong information when it's just copy and paste on the .txt file

Seeing the interface he has on the screenshot i belive hw is using excel 2010. I'm using 2013. Could the error because by an incompatibility on that specific line?
Here's the full code

```
Sub Regisr()
'status bar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "0%..."

'desproteger y actualizar
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("a3").Select
    Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh

'defincion de variables
    'contar referidos viejos
        Dim ok As Integer
        Dim Nook As Integer

        Nook = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("k:k"), "=NO OK")
        ok = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("k:k"), "=Ok") + 2

    'contar referidos nuevos
        Dim Nook2 As Integer
        Nook2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("i:i"), "=NO OK")


    Application.Calculate

'ordenar azul por no ok
    Range("a3", Range("i3").End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=Range("i3"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("a3"), Header:=xlYes

    Application.Calculate

'ordenar naranja por no ok
    Range(Range("k3").End(xlToRight), Range("k3").End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=Range("k3"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("o3"), Header:=xlYes
    Application.Calculate

'borrar referidos viejos
    Dim nook3 As Integer
    If Nook = 0 Then
    nook3 = 1
    Else
    nook3 = Nook
    End If
    Range(Range("l2").End(xlToRight).Offset(ok - 1, 0), Range("l" & nook3).Offset(ok, 0)).ClearContents

Application.Calculate

'agrandar tabla naranja
    If Nook2 > Nook Then
    Dim fondo As String
    Dim derecha As String
    fondo = Range("a2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 11).Address
    derecha = Range("k2").End(xlToRight).Address
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabla26").Resize Range("k2", Range(derecha, fondo))
    Range(Range("k3").End(xlToRight), Range("k3").End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=Range("k3"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("n3"), Header:=xlYes
    End If

'ordenar naranja por no ok
    Range(Range("k3").End(xlToRight), Range("k3").End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=Range("k3"), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("o3"), Header:=xlYes
    Application.Calculate

'status bar
    Application.StatusBar = "25%..."

'copiar referidos nuevos
    Dim nook4 As Integer
    If Nook2 = 0 Then
    nook4 = 1
    Else
    nook4 = Nook2
    End If
    Range(Range("a2").Offset(ok - 1, 0), Range("a" & nook4).Offset(ok, 0)).Copy
    Range(Range("o1").Offset(ok, 0), Range("o1").Offset(ok + nook4 - 1, 0)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    Application.Calculate
    Application.StatusBar = "50%..."

'copiar y pegar clicks de ayer
    Range("e3", Range("e3").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range("n2").End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

'Copiar y pegar clicks de hoy
    Range("d3", Range("d3").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range("n3").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Application.Calculate

'status bar
Application.StatusBar = "75%..."

'reduccion de referidos
    If Nook > Nook2 Then
    Range(Range("k2").Offset(ok - 1, 0), Range("k" & nook3).Offset(ok, 0)).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

'Asegurar columnas ocultas
    'actualizador del resumen
        resuregis = Sheets(6).Name
        Range(Range("l3"), Range("o3").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -3)).Formula = "=if(isnumber(match([@Columna1],'" & resuregis & "'!$A:$A,0)),1,0)"


    'contador de porcentaje
        datos = Sheets(2).Name
        Range(Range("m3"), Range("o3").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2)).Formula = "=if(isnumber(index($1:$1048576,row(),match(" & datos & "!$G$74-1,$1:$1,0))),sum(index($1:$1048576,row(),match(" & datos & "!$G$74-1,$1:$1,0)),-index($1:$1048576,row(),match(" & datos & "!$G$74-2,$1:$1,0))))"

'crear nuevas fechas
    Range("q1:s1").Copy
    Range("k2").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'ocultar columnas
    Dim cantcolum As Integer
    cantcolum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("p1", Range("p1").End(xlToRight))) - 25 + 15

    Range(Cells(1, 16), Cells(1, cantcolum)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True


'volver al inicio
    Range("a1").Select

'proteger
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

 'status bar
    Application.StatusBar = "100%..."
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 438 is property or method not supported. So in the case of Application.DisplayStatusBar, if whatever Application is pointing to does not have a property called DisplayStatusBar you will get this error.

This might be due to different versions of Excel. If your version is later it might support properties and methods that are not included in older versions. Hit the Internet for version differences.

One trick might be to include some debugging so the person getting the error can provide feedback as to where the code was up to. Or include an error handler to capture more on the error.

Comment: The part of the code that's failing is
Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
(I have just fixed the image and should now be legible)
Application is referring to excel itself. "StatusBar" shows a little message on the down left side of the screen (at least in 2013) and "calculate" forces the sheet to refresh its calculations. So far no one has complained about that failing

Comment: Not sure this is it but apparently the patch KB2596927 can cause errors like this but was fixed with KB3025036. So might be worth seeing if the user with the issue has the first patch installed and if so, should also install the second patch. More info at: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-2007-vba-error-object-doesnt-support-this/1484b09b-279e-4070-98e7-d6cb7489d31b

Comment: Failing that, if you're sure about the line of code, replace it with something like:

[NL]
Dim listObject [NL]
Set listObject = Selection.ListObject [NL]
Dim tableObject [NL]
Set tableObject = listObject.TableObject [NL]
tableObject.Refresh [NL]

which hopefully the error line will now give you which member is missing and one more clue to go hunting with. (Can't get the comment to include a new line. I've used [NL] to indicate).

Answer (score 0):

I've already found the error. As mentioned, the object that is refreshig is a table that extracts information from a .txt file.
Linking tables to external objects is a function only available in 2013. Which is why everyone who uses anything previous to 2013 fails to make the code work